# How to call a static method from main class?

Tags: java

I got this code:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> MakeSequence(int N){

    ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if (N<1) {
        return x; // need a null display value?
    }
    else {
        for (int j=N;j>=1;j--)  {
            for (int i=1;i<=j;i++) {
                x.add(Integer.valueOf(j));
            }
        }
    return x;
    }
}
```

I am trying to call it from the main method just like this:

```
System.out.println(MakeSequence (int N));
```

but I get an error...

Any recommendations? Much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What error do you get? Also can you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: You need to qualify the method name or add a static import. What class is your `MakeSequence()` method defined in? Also, for good questions you should include the exact error in its entirety. Don't be vague such as "I get an error".

Comment: N cannot be resolved to a variable and remove int

Comment: `N` looks to be well-defined in that method to me...it's very much the case that it is *not* defined in `main` which is probably where your application is choking.

Comment: `MakeSequence (int N)` is invalid syntax for a method invocation.  If `N` happens to be declared as an appropriately-typed variable in that scope, then the invocation would be `MakeSequence(N)`.  Otherwise, you need to pass an appropriate argument.

Comment: code is working fine when its inside the main method, but want to see if I can make it work outside the main.

Comment: Change the call to `System.out.println(MakeSequence(42));`,  (your free to use some other number than 42 :))

Comment: Hmm.. would you like to pass a function as argument to method MakeSequence? I am really confused of what you are trying here?

Comment: @NorthernFrontSwain you can't call code oustide of a method, every instruction HAS to be in a method

Comment: Its inside a method but not the main method

Comment: @NorthernFrontSwain so no problem. I was refering to the screenshot you put a few minutes ago `int N=1;` wa not in a method

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println(MakeSequence (int N));
```

should be

```
int N = 5; // or whatever value you wish
System.out.println(MakeSequence (N));
```

Just pass a variable of the correct type. You don't say that it is an `int` again;

Comment: Please don't use uppercase variable names.

Comment: Still receive an error that the MakeSequence is not applicable for an argument

Answer (score 4):

You define the method as follow `MakeSequence (int N)`, this means that method expects one parameter, of type `int`, and it'll be called `N` when use inside the method.

So when you call the method, you need to pass an `int` like :

```
MakeSequence(5);
// or
int value = 5;
MakeSequence(value);
```

Then put all of this in a `print` or use the result in a variable

```
System.out.println(MakeSequence(5));
//or
List<Integer> res = MakeSequence(5);
System.out.println(res);
```

All of this code, to call the method, should be in antoher method, like the `main` one

---

- Change `x.add(Integer.valueOf(j));` to `x.add(j);` as `j` is already an `int`
- to follow Java naming conventions : packages, attributes, variables, parameters, method have to start in **lowerCase**, while class, interface should start in **UpperCase**

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is I think that N should be some `int` value not defining the variable in the method call. Like

```
int N = 20;
ClassName.MakeSequence(N);
```

The other issue you will face. As `System.out.println()` only prints string values and you are passing the `ArrayList` object to it, so use it like this `System.out.println(ClassName.MakeSequence(N).toString())`

Comment: Nope, the list as it's own toString() and you'll have a beautiful `[1,2,3,4]` in the console ;)